# How do I take a substring to the first index of a character?

Tags: swift

I'm very new to Swift;  I've spent the morning reading StackOverflow and trying many strategies, in vain, to accomplish the following:

I have a string, say "12345 is your number!"

I want to extract "12345" to a variable.

In Java, I'd do something like:

```
String myStr = "12345 is your number!";
return myStr.substring(0, myStr.indexOf(" "));
```

How do I do something similar in Swift?  I don't want to hard-code any assumptions about what the ending index will be.  It might be 5 characters in, it might not.  I just want to take the substring of everything up to the first occurrence of " ", wherever that might be.

The closest I've gotten so far is:

```
var myMessage  = "12345 is your number!"
myMessage.endIndex.advancedBy(myMessage.characters.count - myMessage.characters.indexOf(" "))
```

but it doesn't compile for reasons I don't fully yet grok("Binary operator '-' cannot be applied to operands of type Distance (aka 'Int') and 'String.CharacterView.Index?'")

Any help on this is appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
myMessage.substringToIndex(myMessage.characters.indexOf(" ")!)
```

Note that in this code I force unwrapped the optional. If you're not guaranteed to have that space in the string, it might make more sense to have the index in a optional binding.

With optional binding, it would look something like this:

```
if let index = myMessage.characters.indexOf(" ") {
    let result = myMessage.substringToIndex(index)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a regex, try this code:

```
var myMessage  = "12345 is your number!"

if let match = myMessage.rangeOfString("-?\\d+", options: .RegularExpressionSearch) {

    print(myMessage.substringWithRange(match)) // 12345
    let myNumber = Int(myMessage.substringWithRange(match)) // Then you can initialize a new variable
}
```

The advantage is that this method extracts only the numbers wherever they are in the `String`

Hope this help ;)

Answer (score 1):

With **Swift 5** you can use:

```
myStr.prefix(upTo: myStr.firstIndex(of: " ") ?? myStr.startIndex)
```

You may need to cast it back to String (`String(myStr.prefix(upTo: myStr.firstIndex(of: " ") ?? myStr.startIndex))`) since it returns a Substring